# Wordpress and Masonry plugin within a fluid grid

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-plugins

Please see the website/page in question: www.lewismalpas.co.uk/blog/portfolio

First time posting on Stack so hopefully some of you wiser members can help me as I have been struggling to get the jQuery masonry plugin (http://masonry.desandro.com) working within my wordpress theme and the fluid grid I am using.

jQuery and the plugin are both being loaded correctly, and I have checked to ensure jQuery is being loaded first, however the script itself where I call the masonry function on a container seems to have no effect whatsoever. I am loading the plugin in header.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery.masonry/jquery.masonry.js"></script>
```

All of my jQuery scripting is placed just before the closing body tag as I am currently calling the masonry plugin on a container div called .twelvecol

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    //jquery masonry    
    jQuery('.twelvecol').imagesLoaded( function(){
        jQuery('.twelvecol').masonry({
            itemSelector : '.project'
         });
    });
});
```

My CSS is as following:

```
.row .twelvecol {
width: 100%;
}

.project {
float: left;
width: 50%;
}
```

Many thanks in advance for your help,

Lewis.

Comment: Any scripting errors? A live example will be necessary to debug I think.

Comment: I have just got a live version running, please let me know if this helps. The plugin should better arrange the div's on the portfolio page - www.lewismalpas.co.uk/blog/portfolio

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed, I had a JS error as I hadn't formed the code correctly for the cycle plugin I am using.